# Checking if Date already exists in database for that User in a Flask Application

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

My Date picker, picks the date on selection and saves it in Database successfully.
But my validation for checking if the Date selected already present in the db for that  user is not seems working.

My Logic was to get  all the Dates for that user and check if the entered form date was present in db list.

Please find the code below:

Route Code

```
@app.route('/timesheet', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def timesheet():
    form = DateFrm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        date=Date(date_comp=form.dt.data,date=current_user)
        db.session.add(date)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your Comp-off has been submited successfully','success')
        return redirect(url_for('hello'))

    return render_template('timesheet.html', form=form)
```

Form code

```
class DateFrm(FlaskForm):
    dt = DateField('DatePicker', format='%Y-%m-%d')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

    def validate_date(self, dt):
        date = Date.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.id).all()
        if dt.data in date:
            raise ValidationError(
                'Date has been already applied')
```

Db Code

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


class User(db.Model,UserMixin):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    username=db.Column(db.String(20),unique=True,nullable=False)
    email=db.Column(db.String(120),unique=True,nullable=False)
    profile_pic=db.Column(db.String(20),nullable=False,default="defaultdp.jpg")
    password=db.Column(db.String(60),nullable=False)

    datatime=db.relationship('Date',backref='date',lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}','{self.email}','{self.profile_pic}')"
class Date(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    date_comp=db.Column(db.DateTime(120),nullable=False)
    user_id=db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('user.id'),nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Date('{self.date_comp}')"
```

HTML code

```
<div class="container">
<form action="#" method="POST">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

    {% if form.dt.errors%}
        {{ form.dt(class="is-invalid") }} 
         <div class="invalid-feedback">
        {% for error in form.dt.errors %}
            <span style="color:red">{{ error }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        {{ form.dt(class='datepicker') }}
    {% endif %} 
    {{form.submit(class_="btn")}}
</form>
</div>
{%endblock contents%}
```

Comment: `date=current_user`??

Comment: @roganjosh sorry i dont get you.
Should i add this condition instead of `if dt.data in date:` ?

Comment: How can a date equal `current_user`?. That's an object from flask-login.

Comment: @roganjosh date is equal to all the dates for the current user from my code, if that was the ask

Comment: Oh  i tried this query on sql and got the list of dates back, so tried in code @roganjosh

Comment: No it isn't. You want to send `user_id=current_user.id` not `date = current_user`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202978/discussion-between-lan-aaroon-and-roganjosh).

Comment: No validation working. I tried even with `date=Date.query.all()` condition which should fail since I already have dates in the DB. But still the submit accepts and gets added in db

Answer (score 0):

You are not validating the **date** before adding it to the DB in your `routes`.
Basically you need to handle that logic in your routes plane. Before you do a call to

```
db.session.add(date)
db.session.commit()
```

Also, in your validation method, you are fetching `date = Date.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.id).all()`. The given statements would give you a **list of Date objects**, now what you are checking in your line

`if dt.data in date:`

is that if the given date(as a DateTime field) exists in a **list of Date objects** which evaluates to `False` every time since in your models, you have defined `Date` to be not a `DateField`, but a class consisting other attributes too, hence no exception is raised.